# Peewee Connection pooling with postgresql 9.4 and JSON fields support

Tags: python, json, connection-pooling, peewee, postgresql-9.4

Knowing that there is already support for [connection pooling for Postgres](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/database.html) in Peewee, and also support for [JSON fields in Postgres](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#pgjson), I would like to know if **PooledPostgresqlDatabase** actually supports those JSON fields too, and if not how can i do to get that working as a **PostgresqlExtDatabase**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an class named **PooledPostgresqlExtDatabase** which supports both pooling in the way **PostgresqlExtDatabase** does but with connection pooling support:

```
from playhouse.pool import PooledPostgresqlExtDatabase

db = PooledPostgresqlExtDatabase(
    'my_database',
    max_connections=8,
    stale_timeout=300,
    user='postgres')
```